# Can cider ferment in under a week?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, cider, fruit

I started a cider brew one week ago and when taking the gravity today it was 1.000, the starting gravity was 1.065 which according to the calculators online I have an abv of 8.5% (ish). Is it possible for my cider to have reached this abv in under a week. The bubbles where coming fast and hard all week but have died down over the last 2 days.

Additional info;

The brew itself is 25 litres with 20 litres of it being apple juice from concentrate 4 litres rhubarb and apple juice and litre a strawberry and rhubarb syrup (frozen strawberries and canned rhubarb reduced down with 1kg of sugar). I used M02 yeast from mangrove jack and 1tsp of fanmax bio yeast nutrient. Finally I added diced stalks of rhubarb to the brew.

I tasted the brew today and there is not a hint of any of the other flavours just tastes like hard cider (not really complaining just disappointed) and smells very very lightly sulfury.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using wine yeast it is common for a ferment to finish in a week. I've had commercial sized batches of grapes (multiple tons) finish in 7 days depending on how hot it is and the type of yeast.

The sulfur smell may or may not dissipate with time. I would rack off the yeast soon as that can sometimes contribute to hydrogen sulfide production.